# Elasticsearch: cURL to Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, curl, elasticsearch

I am using Ajax request for elasticsearch to get search results.
Finally, I have found the query which I have to go for. (This is a follow up question to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44608208/ajax-query-format-with-elasticsearch))

Here is the query in cURL:

```
[~]$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/firebase/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
> {"query": {"match": {"song": {"query": "i am in", "operator": "and"}}}}'
```

> Result:

```
{
  "took" : 286,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.8630463,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "firebase",
        "_type" : "song",
        "_id" : "0001",
        "_score" : 0.8630463,
        "_source" : {
          "song" : "i am in california",
          "song_name" : "hello",
          "song_url" : "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/..."
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This query gives me result exactly what I need.
When I am using the same request with AJAX, it gives me a bad request.

**Ajax.js**

***Case 1:***

```
$(function() {
    $('#message').keyup(function() {    
        var query = {
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "song": {
                        "query": $("#message").val(),
                        "operator": "and"
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        console.log(JSON.stringify(query));

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:9200/firebase/_search",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: query,
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'json'
        });

    });

});
```

Result in console:

[image]

***Case 2***: If I convert the 'data' using JSON.stringify, it gives me:[image]

***Case 3***: If I change the query structure as following and use JSON.stringify on 'data':

```
var query = {
    query: {
        match: {
            song: {
                query: $("#message").val(),
                operator: "and"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Result is:

[image]

I am not sure what's the issue here, the query is correct because using the same with cURL I am getting correct results in bash. Question is how to correctly create the Ajax request here. Pointers would be appreciated.

**Edit**: And yes I have enabled CORS in elasticsearch.yml:

```
http.cors.enabled : true
http.cors.allow-origin : "*"
http.cors.allow-methods : OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers : X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type, Content-Length
```

**Edit1**: Chrome, Network data underneath so as to provide more information:
[image]

**Edit2**: Full error response is below:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/firebase/_search] contains unrecognized parameters: [query[match][song][operator]], [query[match][song][query]]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/firebase/_search] contains unrecognized parameters: [query[match][song][operator]], [query[match][song][query]]"},"status":400}
```

Comment: instead of localhost you should use server ip address, where elasticsearch is installed

Comment: When my query structure was simply - data: {  'q':  $('#message').val(), } it was working fine Alex. There was no issue with localhost. But since normal query was not solving my problem, I wanted to use match, hence the change. Hence, I am not sure localhost is an issue though I will check and come back.

Comment: Doesn't work. Tried using both 127.0.0.1 (loopback) and 192.168.0.1 (site-local) on 9200. Same issue understandably. Plus, my elasticsearch is running locally for now anyway.

Comment: And again, cURL is using localhost as well and working still. Guess must be some other issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience the behavior of GET methods with a body is sometimes hard to predict. Actually, elastic search supports GET with body  but I also had some strange results depending on the configuration of the servers, proxies and so on... The documentation even highlights the problems with javascript ([search with GET](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_empty_search.html)).

Usually, using POST instead of GET helps to resolve these problems or at least to have a further debug option.

Comment: Damn awesome is what it is! Thanks so much, works like a charm! And thanks for the doc reference as well.

Answer (score 1):

For those coming from Google, another way to solve this problem - or even if the `POST` solution doesn't work - is to use `source` parameter in the URL, as mentioned in docs[1].

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:9200/firebase/_search?source_content_type=application/json&source=" + JSON.stringify(query),
  contentType: 'application/json',
  success: searchSuccess,
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

[1] https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_request_body_in_query_string