# Bonsai Elasticsearch add-on: 401 Unauthorised Error

Tags: ajax, firebase, elasticsearch, heroku, bonsai-elasticsearch

In order to deploy my firebase application, which uses Elasticsearch I am looking at using Heroku Bonsai Add-on.

Everything is set, issue is I am getting an unauthorised error on passing Ajax request. Exactly the same code has been working smoothly on local ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612315/elasticsearch-curl-to-ajax-request)) but not on deploying.

**Ajax.jx**

```
$(function() {
    $('#message').keyup(function() {
        var query = {
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "song": {
                        "query": $("#message").val(),
                        "operator": "and"
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://<username>:<password>@xxxwood-5671445.xx-xxxx-1.bonsaisearch.net/firebase/_search",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            crossDomain: true,
            data: JSON.stringify(query),
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'json'
        });

    });

});
```

I have used the correct username and password for my Bonsai URL but it's not working.

Console error:
[image]

Chrome console error:[image]

cURL though works all right:

```
[~]$ curl -XGET 'https://<username>:<password>@dogwood-5671445.xx-xxxx-1.bonsaisearch.net/firebase/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{"query": {"match": {"song": {"query": "i am in", "operator": "and"}}}}'
```

> cURL result:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.4048493,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "firebase",
      "_type" : "song",
      "_id" : "0001",
      "_score" : 1.4048493,
      "_source" : {
        "song" : "i am in california",
        "song_name" : "hello",
        "song_url" : "https://xxx.xx/xxxx"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

**Question: What am I missing?**

Comment: What happens if you attach the auth credentials in the header like so?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5507289/2592585

Comment: If you could please add that as an answer so that I could accept it. It was a header issue as you rightly pointed out. Thanks.

Comment: Also, if you're just searching from Ajax, then Bonsai lets you enable a "read-only" mode that doesn't need credentials. That way you're not distributing your credentials out to the public :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely Ajax wasn't passing the credentials from the URL. Attach auth via HTTP header like so:  [How to use Basic Auth with jQuery and AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-with-jquery-and-ajax/5507289#5507289)